# Horizontally expanding textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea, expand

right now we're using Jack Moore's Autosize (http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize) which does the vertial expanding just fine. But is there a solution for expanding vertically as well as horizontally (up to a max-width)?